# Will I lose progress if I unlock items and bases before starting the first mission?

Tags: just-cause-3

I conquered all the bases in Just Cause 3 and haven't done any mission/upgrade. I was wondering when I start the first mission will I lose all the bases and my best guns and then have to start from scratch from that mission? Or will I have everything including guns weapons vehicles and keep all my conquered bases when I do the mission and unlock the wingsuit and everything else that comes with the missions?

Comment: By "conquered all the bases" do you mean just the bases specifically, are all the various "oppressed" POI's? As in, are DiRivello's forces still in control of any areas, cities, military radar towers, etc. in your case?

Answer (score 3):

After completing only two or three missions, I went through and liberated every single province in the game.

**Now playing the missions all the bases, vehicles, and equipment I had liberated / unlocked are still available**.

This actually makes some of the missions extremely easy, as instead of having to drive a tank through enemy territory, it is a relatively easy drive from beginning to end.

Answer (score 1):

You should not lose guns or upgrades.

However, if you haven't unlocked the wingsuit yet (which I am pretty sure unlocks during the tutorial), there is still a copious amount of gameplay for you to complete. There are three islands, and the first part of the game is only on the first.

Source: 200+ hours in JC3

Answer (score 0):

No, but I prefer to follow the missions. The three cetrecom bases all have some sort of weapon (air strike, Bavarium nuke, and something else) that can be removed by doing the missions. Falcon Maxine is nearly impossible to liberate without doing this, as it launches a bavarium NUKE at you every 10 seconds or so. This coupled with the massive size of the base, makes it insanely hard to liberate. So I recommend doing the missions first. You do you though, your progress will still be saved.